# How to construct a dynamic rewrite rule for child pages that passes more than one query var

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting, urls, parameter

I get a 404 error

```
        parent-page/any-child-page/?var1=x&var2=y&var3=z
```

This is what I have so far:

I want to have the rule cover any child page

```
        add_rewrite_rule('^project-centers/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/?$', 'index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&var1=$matches[2]&var2=$matches[3]&var3=$matches[4]','top');
```

I can get the values without the rewrite rule using:
`/project-centers/kitchen/?var1=x&var2=y&var3=z`

Here is the query var_dump:

```
array(67) {
  ["pagename"]=>
  string(7) "kitchen"
  ["project_name"]=>
  string(7) "kitchen"
  ["var1"]=>
  string(1) "x"
  ["var2"]=>
  string(1) "y"
  ["var3"]=>
  string(1) "z"
  ["error"]=>
...
```

What and I missing?

Comment: Does this page work ok if you go to it directly? `index.php?pagename=kitchen&var1=x&var2=y&var3=z`

Comment: Yes, with permalinks set to plain, but the url converts to `?page_id=9626&var1=x&var2=y&var3=z`

Yes, with permalinks set to post name, but the URL converts to `project-centers/kitchen/?var1=x&var2=y&var3=z`

Answer (score 0):

First thing to check is make sure you visit permalinks page, or call the `flush_rewrite_rules` function *once* after you call add_rewrite_rules otherwise the rule will not get applied.

So to restate your question, is it correct that you're trying to achieve rewriting this:

```
example.com/project-centers/kitchen/x/y/z
```

To this:

```
eample.com/index.php?pagename=kitchen&var1=x&var2=y&var3=z
```

If that's correct, your code looks like it should work, but if it's not you should try writing your rewrite rule like this:

```
add_rewrite_rule(
    '^project-centers/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$', 
    'index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&var1=$matches[2]&var2=$matches[3]&var3=$matches[4]',
    'top'
);
```

This change is to make it clear to the regex that it should never match a `/` inside any of the matched strings, otherwise it can easily do this and things get complicated.

**Remember to either visit the permalinks page, or call the `flush_rewrite_rules` function *once* (not on every page load) after you call add_rewrite_rules otherwise the rule will not get applied!**

Let me know if that helps

Comment: I flushed the rewrite rules both ways.  I even just called it in the functions.php file.  

I know this is overkill but here is what I have for my code.   

    `add_action('init', 'ms_rewrite_rules');
function ms_rewrite_rules() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^project-centers/(.+)/?$','index.php?pagename=project-centers/$matches[1]&project_name=$matches[1]','top'); 

    add_rewrite_rule(
    '^project-centers/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$', 
    'index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&var1=$matches[2]&var2=$matches[3]&var3=$matches[4]',
    'top');
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}`

Comment: I still am receiving the 404 error.  Sorry about the messy comments.